# Double Query lines

Tags: sql, ms-access

I had created a query that worked without issues, which I then modified without saving the original. I do not remember the exact changes I made (I should keep a log, for future references, I know).

Following the changes I made, certain lines are doubled, in spite of the fact that `LOTNO`is unique per each given `BLDNO`.

The main table is supposed to be `SGLO`.

I do not understand why this is happening, as far as I can see from the relationship tree, everyline should be unique. I am therefore posting this in the hope someone from the community may be kind enough to point out my mistake(s).

The code is as follows (broken down by each intended column):

```
SELECT ANSC_LOC.SOCNAM1 AS Locataire, 
SGBA.ACTV AS Flag_Loc, 
SGBA.CTRDTE AS [Date Signature], 
IIf((CDate(Left([Date Fin],4) & "/" & Mid([Date Fin],5,2) & "/" & Right([Date Fin],2)))<Date(),"Vide",IIf((CDate(Left([Date Fin],4) & "/" & Mid([Date Fin],5,2) & "/" & Right([Date Fin],2)))>Date() And CDate(Left([Date début],4) & "/" & Mid([Date début],5,2) & "/" & Right([Date début],2))>Date(),"Futur","Occupé")) AS Disponibilité, 
SGBA.DEBDTE AS [Date début], 
SGBA.FINDTE AS [Date Fin], 
[SGLO]![LOYBAS] AS [Loyer de base annuel], 
SGBA.LOYBAN, SGBA.LOYBAS, SGBA.LOYPER AS [Périodicité loyer], 
IIf(Format([SGLO]![LOYBAS],"Standard")>0 And [SGBA]![LOYLRVIDX]>0,([SGLO]![LOYBAS]*[SGBA]![LOYLRVIDX]/[SGBA]![IDXBAS]),[SGLO]![LOYBAS]) AS [Loyer actuel annuel indexe], 
IIf([SGBA]![LOYPER]="1" And [SGBA]![LOYBAN]>0,[SGBA]![LOYAPN],IIf([SGBA]![LOYPER]="3" And [SGBA]![LOYBAN]>0,[SGBA]![LOYAPN]/3,IIf([SGBA]![LOYPER]="5" And [SGBA]![LOYBAN]>0,[SGBA]![LOYAPN]/12,IIf([SGBA]![LOYPER]="1" And [SGBA]![LOYBAS]>0,[SGBA]![LOYAPS],IIf([SGBA]![LOYPER]="3" And [SGBA]![LOYBAS]>0,[SGBA]![LOYAPS]/3,IIf([SGBA]![LOYPER]="5" And [SGBA]![LOYBAS]>0,[SGBA]![LOYAPS]/12)))))) AS [Dernier loyer mensuel indexe], 
ANSC_PRO.SOCNAM1 AS Propriétaire, 
ANSC_LOT.SOCNAM1 AS Bâtiment, 
SGLO.BLDNO AS [Code Bâtiment], 
SGLO.LOTNO AS [Numéro Lot], 
SGLO.TYP AS [Code type lot], 
LOTSTYPE.TEXT AS [Type lot], 
[SRF]/100 AS Surface, 
SGLO.SIT AS Adresse, 
SGLO.ETG AS [Code lot], 
SGLO.BLXNO AS [Code Bail], 
SGLO.ETGNUM AS Etage, 
SGLO.QUOTI AS Quotités, 
Photos.[Adresse photo]
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                (SGLO INNER JOIN ANSC_PRO ON SGLO.PRO = ANSC_PRO.NOTIERS) 
            INNER JOIN SGBA ON SGLO.BLXNO = SGBA.BLXNO) 
        INNER JOIN ANSC_LOC ON SGBA.LOC = ANSC_LOC.NOTIERS) 
    INNER JOIN LOTSTYPE ON SGLO.TYP = LOTSTYPE.LOTTYP) 
INNER JOIN 
    (
        (SGBD INNER JOIN ANSC_LOT ON SGBD.ANSC = ANSC_LOT.NOTIERS) 
    LEFT JOIN Photos ON SGBD.BLDNO = Photos.[Code Immeuble]) ON SGLO.BLDNO = SGBD.BLDNO;
```

And this is the relationship tree :

[image: Relationship Tree]

Comment: Each building can have multiple Photos records? What happens if you remove Photos table from query?

Comment: I don't see the issue immediately, and It would take me an hour to duplicate all those tables.  I don't wanna.  If I had done that I would rebuild the query piece by simple piece until something happened I didn't expect.   You can also work backwards from a copy of the query, as It happens the table relationships in a query can be adjusted without affecting the table relationships in the database.  You should find that when you remove a certain table(s) the duplication disappears, as well as some variable you wanted in the query results. start figuring it out from there.

Comment: @June17

Each building has its own photo. The answer to your question is : Nothing in particular.

As I've looked around online, I noticed I had linked the same field in the SGBD table to two different fields in two different tables (SGLO and Photos), which apparently causes an outer join effect, resulting in double lines.

The above link was a change I had made previously for some reason that had made sense at the time.

Comment: @Mazoula

I actually did start from scratch and took a look at the generated SQL code with every step, which led me to understand I had mistakenly linked the same field in the SGBA table to two different fields in two different tables, resulting in an outer join of sorts.

Comment: way to go :) I upvoted your comment to kind of mark it as the answer